# The review close votes queue is not (always) rendering code formatted text

Tags: bug, review-queues

I have just had two reviews in the close vote queue where code formatted text was not displayed (one was an audit). None of the other close-vote reviews I had so far had code.

For example, [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/33810426) is rendered as:

[image: question in close votes review queue rendered without code]

The [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75391853/maven-intellij-always-using-remote-repository-for-artifacts) is rendered as:

[image: original question rendered with code]

Also notice how the XML of the question is rendered with replacement characters, which suggests this is a font issue.

The other one was [an audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/33800565):

[image: audit rendered without code]

The [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75228188/sql-join-and-order-by) of the audit:

[image]

I'm using Firefox 109.0.1 (64-bit) on Windows 11.

I cannot reproduce the behaviour in Chrome, nor in a private session in Firefox. The interesting difference is that the font used for the code block is CascadiaMonoRoman in the review queue, while in normal question view it uses Cascadia Mono Regular. In the Firefox private session it also uses Cascadia Mono Regular for the review queue (when logged out and logged in).

Interestingly, the issue persisted after throwing away "Cached Web Content" and reloading the page, but after also throwing away "Cookies and Site Data" and restarting Firefox, it is now rendering correctly, and is using Cascadia Mono Regular for the review page (instead of CascadiaMonoRoman like before). I wonder if this might have been some old setting or profile data lurking on my machine.

Comment: I do not reproduce on Chrome.

Comment: @CodyGray I just tried in Chrome and it indeed renders it correctly. Interestingly enough, when I open a private session in Firefox and open the page, it also renders correctly.

Comment: Check with the debugging tools and see what font Firefox is deciding to render that code as on the review page. That might give a clue.

Comment: Font used is CascadiaMonoRoman, while in normal question view it uses Cascadia Mono Regular. In the Firefox private session it also uses Cascadia Mono Regular

Comment: Hmm, the issue persisted after throwing away "Cached Web Content" and reloading the page, but after also throwing away "Cookies and Site Data" and restarting Firefox, it is now rendering correctly, and is using Cascadia Mono Regular for the review page (instead of CascadiaMonoRoman like before). I wonder if this might have been some old setting or profile data lurking on my machine. Should I keep this question, close it as not reproducible or just delete it?

Comment: Surely related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386560/176034